# Can't start subprocess 'swriter' via button.clicked.connect, if any instance of swriter is already opened on local PC

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.7

I tried to open OpenOffice 'swriter' program via Subprocess in Python 3.

If I try to run the subprocess via button.clicked.connect, it only works, if no instance of swriter is already active on my PC, otherwise it doesn't work and Widget freezes.

When I forced stopping GUI, the subprocess opens the desired file. (looks like it has been locked as read only before)

However, if I started the same method call  directly, i.e. not via button.clicked.connect, it works as expected, no matter if any instance of swriter was opened before or not.

Of course, subprocess is intended to be opened on demand via button.clicked.connect, and that's exactly what doesn't work properly

```
import sys
import subprocess

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QWidget)


class Window(QWidget):

def invoke_subprocess(self):
    subprocess.run(["swriter", r"Z:/temp_file.odt"], capture_output=True, encoding="utf-8") 
    
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle("QHBoxLayout Example")
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    someButton= QtWidgets.QPushButton()
    someButton.setText("Button")
    layout.addWidget(someButton,6)
    someButton.clicked.connect(self.invoke_subprocess)  # not working if any instance of swriter is already opened
    self.setLayout(layout)
    self.invoke_subprocess() # this line is executing properly in any case

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If you want to start `swriter` as an independent process (on Windows), I would recommend using the `start.exe` helper to do so: `os.system('start swriter z:/temp_file.odt')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint, Tyler, it works properly now,  in all scenarios